# Essential supremum of Fourier transform.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $K\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ is symmetric s.t.
$$
\text{ess sup}_{t\in \mathbb R/\{0\}} \frac{|1-\hat K(t)|}{|t|^{\beta}}\leq A,
$$
where $\hat K$ is the Fourier transform.

Theorem 1.5 in "Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation" by B.Tsybakov claim that the condition above is equivalent to
$$
\exists t_0, A_0<\infty, \text{ess sup}_{0<t\leq|t_0|} \frac{|1-\hat K(t)|}{|t|^{\beta}}\leq A_0.
$$
I'm not sure why this is true. Can Fourier transform of $K$ be bounded by a polynomial at infinity?

**Remark:** Exercise 1.6 in the same book adds the assumption that $K\in L^{\infty}(R)$, which makes the equivalence quite obvious. I wonder if the equivalence still holds without such an assumption.

Comment: Exercise 1.6 in the same book adds the assumption that $\hat K\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, which makes the equivalence quite obvious. I wonder if this assumption is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "symmetric" means "even"  it's clearly false. Because $\hat K$ can be any symmetric $L^2$ function...